# list index out of range error when sorting a list

Tags: python, list

so i am trying to sort a list of members by their 'id' in a new list. the problem is that python tells me that the index is out of range which i don't understand since i do have a value at that index spot in the list.

here my code

```
members = [
  {'id': 1, 'firstname': 'johnny', 'lastname': 'doe'    },
  {'id': 3, 'firstname': 'sky',    'lastname': 'smith'  },
  {'id': 4, 'firstname': 'mary',   'lastname': 'johnes' },
  {'id': 2, 'firstname': 'frank',  'lastname': 'sanchez'}
]

NewMembers = []
i = 0
ids = 1

while len(NewMembers) != len(members):
    if ids == members[i]['id']:
        NewMembers.append(members[i])
        ids += 1
    else:
        i += 1

print(NewMembers)
```

output

```
line 8, in <module>
if ids == mymembers[i]['id']:
          ~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You're looking for 1.  You find it an entry #0.  Now `ids` is 2 and `i` is 0.    You go looking for 2, but there is no entry with an id of 2. so you keep bumping `i` until it runs off the end of the list.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built-in `sorted()` function?

Comment: Do you just want `members.sort( key=lambda i: i['id'] )`?

Comment: This algorithm only works if all the IDs are sequential. But you're missing ID 2, so it runs off the end of the list looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a lambda expression:

```
NewMembers = members.copy()
NewMembers.sort(key=lambda member : member['id'])
```

If you don't want to use lambdas:

```
def getID(member):
    return member['id']

NewMembers = members.copy()
NewMembers.sort(key=getID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your logic with your sample. It will only work if the IDs are already sorted. Otherwise `i` will continue to be incremented until an out of bounds access occurs.

You should be using `sorted` which allows you to specify a key to sort on. In this case a lambda that returns the id of each element.

```
print(sorted(members, key=lambda x: x['id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If You wanna select people with specific id You can use the code below:

```
members = [{'id': 1, 'firstname': 'johnny', 'lastname': 'doe'},{'id': 3, 'firstname': 'sky', 'lastname': 'smith'},{'id': 4, 'firstname': 'mary', 'lastname': 'johnes'},{'id': 3, 'firstname': 'frank', 'lastname': 'sanchez'}]

NewMembers = []
i = 0
ids = 1
while i != len(members):
    if ids == members[i]["id"]:
        NewMembers.append(members[i])
    i += 1

print(NewMembers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a value, but it became too big
At one moment your cycle is reaching i>3, that means it is trying to get

```
if ids == members[4]['id']
```

So this is out of **range of your values**

If you want to use cycle, much better to use "for". Here's how:

```
members = [{'id': 1, 'firstname': 'johnny', 'lastname': 'doe'},{'id': 3, 'firstname': 'sky', 'lastname': 'smith'},{'id': 4, 'firstname': 'mary', 'lastname': 'johnes'},{'id': 3, 'firstname': 'frank', 'lastname': 'sanchez'}]

new_members = []
max_difference = 0

for m in members:
    if m['id'] > max_difference: max_difference = m['id']

for n, member in enumerate(members):
    if n == 0:
        new_members.append(members[n])
        continue

    right_i = -1
    left_i = -1
    duplicate = -1
    right_difference = -max_difference
    left_difference = max_difference
    for i, new_member in enumerate(new_members):

        if (
            abs(new_member['id'] - member['id']) == new_member['id'] - member['id']
            and
            right_difference < new_member['id'] - member['id']
            ):
            right_difference = new_member['id'] - member['id']
            right_i = i
        elif (
            abs(new_member['id'] - member['id']) != new_member['id'] - member['id']
            and
            left_difference > new_member['id'] - member['id']
            ):
            left_i = i
        elif new_member['id'] - member['id'] == 0:
            new_members.append(members[n])
            duplicate = i
            break

    if duplicate != -1: new_members.insert(duplicate, members[n])
    elif left_i != -1: new_members.insert(left_i+1, members[n])
    else: new_members.insert(right_i, members[n])
            

print(new_members)
```

Not the most beautiful sorting algo, but uses only cycles and works 100% with any amount of input
(if id is integer)